# Why is ARC Welder window so narrow (Acer Chromebook 15, Full HD 1980 x 1020)

Tags: google-chrome-arc

[image: ARC Welder on Chromebook]

Acer Chromebook 15 CB5-571-39VM Intel Core i3-5005U 4GB 32GB SSD
Full-HD Display Chrome OS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about the appearance of a developer tool, not programming.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. May be Google should improve their wording on https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc   ...   Test your app
Open ARC Welder, attach your APK, and select your options. Click Launch App to test your app. When testing, file a bug if something doesn't work, or find us on Stack Overflow (tag: google-chrome-arc) for help.

Comment: Issue created on Chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=474321

Answer (score 0):

ARC Welder v2 will solve it,
-> see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=474321